# Does this series converge or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

$$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\left(\ln k\right)^{\ln k}}$$

I've tried limit comparison with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and also Cauchy condensation test but nothing seems to work. With the condensation test I reached this point $$\frac{2^k}{k\cdot \sqrt{2^k}\cdot c^k}$$ where $c=\left(\ln2\right)^{\ln2}$ and then got stuck. Root and fracion tests create issues with the ln so I can't think of anything else

Comment: One "solves" equations or problems. One "calculate" or "evaluate" series.

Comment: forgot to write converge diverge. i apologise

Comment: It's not clear from your post if you want to calculate the series or just determine if it converges or diverges.

Comment: so for convergence divergence its evaluate right?

Comment: @Throwaway547: The series is convergent and comparison with $1/n^2$ is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $k\in\Bbb N$,$$\frac{2^k}{k\sqrt{2^k}c^k}=\frac1k\left(\frac{\sqrt2}c\right)^k\to\infty,$$since $\frac{\sqrt2}c>1$. Therefore, your series diverges.

Comment: Thanks a ton i hadnt noticed

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: in the case that it was $\frac{1}{k^2}$ that converges would the whole series still diverge? Abel's test talks only about conversion if im not mistaken

Comment: Yes, it still would diverge, for the same reason.

Comment: The original series is convergent though. No?

Comment: Yes. Please un-mark my answer as accepted, so that I can delete it.

Comment: I assumed that you wrote about the Cauchy condensation test was correct, but it was not. We have$$\frac{2^k}{\sqrt{2^k}\ln(2^k)^{\ln(2^k)}}=\frac{2^k}{\sqrt{2^k}(k\ln(2))^{k\ln(2)}}\ne\frac{2^k}{k\sqrt{2^k}c^k}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $k > e^{e^2}$ we have $\ln \ln k > 2$ and

$$(\ln k )^{\ln k} = e^{\ln \ln k \cdot \ln k}= k ^{\ln\ln k}> k^2$$

Thus, for all sufficiently large $k$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(\ln k )^{\ln k}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} k^2}< \frac{1}{k^2},$$

and the series converges by the comparison test.